# How to interpret P-values in R (in the context of Dunn Test)

Tags: r, p-value

Here is my output from a Dunn Test. I'm having trouble understanding the adjusted P-values. All the numbers are long and have 'e-' or 'e+' in the middle. I vaguely understand that in the common significant p-values e.g. <2.2e-16, it means it's very low. What I want to understand here is whether my p-values are significant or not. But because they all have 'e-' or 'e+' in the middle I am unsure if they are actually all negative numbers, or if some, with 'e+' are positive.

In short, are the adjusted p-values significant or not?

```
(1) 2.655642e-228
(2) 0.000000e+00
(3) 1.642849e-21
(4) 1.406332e-29
(5) 2.064938e-95
(6) 1.332631e-204
(7) 1.878217e-57
(8) 4.215987e-58
(9) 1.006057e-147
(10) 3.755779e-05
```

Comment: It means they are very close to 0, at least below the typical alpha threshold of 0.05.

Comment: Hi @Phil thanks so much for your comment. So to clarify, are all these p-values significant, that is below 0.05? Including the p-values with 'e+' in them? I was beginning to think that maybe these are positive numbers and therefore not significant.

Comment: The term "significant" doesn't actually mean anything. The p-value represents the probability of getting an effect at least as extreme as the one observed if you hypothesized that there is no effect. 

In this case, the probabilities are so low that you can safely reject the notion that there is no effect. What you consider "significant" is when the p-value is below a certain threshold that you specify prior to doing the test. Commonly, this is set to 0.05, but it can be whatever you wish (hence my earlier comment that it is not a meaningful term).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clearing that up. I totally appreciate your point. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these values are significant by any sensible standard. The only "+" value is essentially zero. You can print values without scientific notation as follows:

```
pvals <- c(2.655642e-228, 0.000000e+00, 1.642849e-21, 1.406332e-29, 2.064938e-95,
      1.332631e-204, 1.878217e-57, 4.215987e-58, 1.006057e-147, 3.755779e-05)
options(scipen=6)
round(pvals, 6)
#  [1] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000038
```

The `scipen` option indicates that scientific notation should not be used unless the value is beyond -6. Then we round the values to that number of decimal places. You can see that they are all near 0 and much lower than .01 or even .001.

Comment: I also found this link which does the same thing just without the hassle of doing it in R, https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/scientific-notation-converter.php?fbclid=IwAR2MRSR5zaJF4ONGOcr6GRyttrknerIsXIVKiTQykmhHlforbK3Xo-jm9pI